# Object data provider with datagridcombo box mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

i need to know how can i user object dataprovider binded to datagridcombobox where the data provider calls a method in view model that gets data from data base ana put in a observalbe collection markets and i want to show these markets in a datagridcombobox column where user can select market while adding or editing data rows.

I have seen  examples of how using dataobject provider with enums but this is not my case so kindly advice with an example .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty easy to use the `ObjectDataProvider`, Just pass in the class and the method name to call.

**ObjectDataProvider:**

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:ViewModelnamespace"

<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myData" 
                    ObjectType="{x:Type ViewModelnamespace:MyViewModel}" 
                    MethodName="GetData">        
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

**Data:**

```
namespace ViewModelnamespace
{   
    public class MyViewModel
    {
          public ObservableCollection<SomeThing> GetData()      
          {
              return //your data
          }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myData}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it and get back to u. I am new to wpf , i need to know the difference btn using objectdataprovider and binding the combobox directy to collection in viewmodel , which approach is better?